# Drawing Image on Canvas From Computer

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to make my first game. Of course, I am trying to make a background image. I am using this object with the link and the DrawImage(); function to draw my image on the screen.

```
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

This gives the desired result, and I can load the image on the screen, but I need to be online in order to load it, since it is a link.

I have tried replacing the link with a file path, but alas, it did not work.

Is there a way to load a image file from my computer to Canvas, and not be online in order to run the program?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

-IronApe

Comment: you can use an <input type=file> to load a local image. use URL.createObjectURL(theFile) to turn the file into a URL

Comment: Could you show us how you tried replacing the link with the file path? Also for clarification, is this image file on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You simply need the image to be in the same directory (or you need to locate it's path). For example if we had our directory setup like this:

```
myFile.html
myImage.jpg
```

Then you can do:

```
imageObj.src = 'myImage.jpg';
```

Or say for example you have a directory for images: `imgs`.

```
myFile.html
imgs
 -> myImage.jpg
```

Then you can do:

```
imageObj.src = 'imgs/myImage.jpg';
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the HTML file is on your computer. Most of the time if the file is hosted on a server, you cannot access the client's file system without using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes but the OP did say: *from my computer to Canvas*. I'm assuming that meant that he made a copy of the image to his local machine.

Comment: *I have tried replacing the link with a file path, but alas, it did not work* So the page is not opened with the file protocol `file://`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a relative path. For example, if you download that image and save it in the same dir where your html is, this would work:

```
imageObj.src = 'darth-vader.jpg';
```

Another example, say it's in the `images` directory, then this will work:

```
imageObj.src = 'images/darth-vader.jpg';
```

Etc... You just need to specify the right path to the image relative to the file you're calling it from.

Comment: By the way, OP clearly says *I have tried replacing the link with a file path, but alas, it did not work.* So I suspect the page might be hosted on a server (probably localhost).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Could be, but he shouldn't use `file:///` anyway. Relative paths should work from anywhere.